# How can I programmatically detect ssh authentication types available?

Tags: security, ssh, monitoring, openssh

I'd like to write a monitoring plugin that checks various hosts on my network to make sure that password or interactive SSH authentication is not enabled. That is, I need to write code that:

1. Connects to an SSH port.
2. Enumerates available authentication methods.
3. Verifies that only key based authentication is possible.

Methods using either python or bourne sh code (using `ssh`) is most interesting to me, but other languages, libraries or hints are appreciated too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm currently building one myself, however, you can force ssh to output (to STDERR) the supported methods by using the PreferredAuthentications option.  This can easily be parsed with grep/python/language of choice.

```
HostA$ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=none HostB
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).
HostA$ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=none HostC
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive,hostbased).
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Thanks. Would be interested in your code if it ends up being open source...

Comment: Unfortunately, this particular block of code won't be able to be open-sourced.  Sorry.  That's why I wanted to share the initial thoughts before I need to stop talking about it.

Answer (score 7):

[RFC 4252](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4252.txt), which defines authentication in SSH, says the following:

> Authentication methods are identified by their name, as defined in
>      [SSH-ARCH].  The "none" method is reserved, and MUST NOT be listed as
>      supported.  However, it MAY be sent by the client.  The server MUST
>      always reject this request, unless the client is to be granted access
>      without any authentication, in which case, the server MUST accept
>      this request.  The main purpose of sending this request is **to get the
>      list of supported methods** from the server.

So you can send a request for *none* authentication to get the list of supported ones. 
However, authentication itself occurs after certain lower-level actions take place (key exchange is one of them) so you might need to write a part of SSH protocol in sh script, which is probably a non-trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the `nmap` built-in NSE script called [ssh-auth-methods](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssh-auth-methods.html) to do this:

```
# nmap -p 22 --script ssh-auth-methods 192.168.1.2

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-12-26 00:56 GMT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.2
Host is up (0.027s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
| ssh-auth-methods:
|   Supported authentication methods:
|     publickey
|_    keyboard-interactive
MAC Address: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF (Apple)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.40 seconds
```

In addition, someone has made a [similar python3 script](https://github.com/mmcco/ssh-auth-methods).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution based on Eadwacer's answer:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -u

for ip in 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2; do
        ok=0
        for try in {1..3}; do
                echo "$ip: try #$try"
                OUT="$(timeout -s KILL 30s ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=none "root@$ip" 2>&1)"
                RES="$(echo "$OUT" | fgrep ': Permission denied (publickey).')"
                if [ "$RES" != "" ]; then
                        ok=1
                        echo '  Auth is OK.'
                        break
                else
                        echo '  Auth is BAD.'
                fi
                sleep 5
        done
        if [ "$ok" -eq 1 ]; then
                echo "$ip: final result: OK"
        else
                echo "$ip: final result: FAIL" >&2
                echo "  ssh output: $OUT" >&2
        fi
done
```

The retries are there to avoid false-positives due to intermittent connection failures like timeouts, etc.

Here is how a sample run looks like:

```
$ ./ssh-assert-key-auth-only.sh
1.1.1.1: try #1
  Auth is OK.
1.1.1.1: final result: OK
2.2.2.2: try #1
  Auth is BAD.
2.2.2.2: try #2
  Auth is BAD.
2.2.2.2: try #3
  Auth is BAD.
2.2.2.2: final result: FAIL
  ssh output: root@2.2.2.2: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Debug info is sent to `stdout` and can easily be muted for non-interactive runs:

```
$ ./ssh-assert-key-auth-only.sh >/dev/null
2.2.2.2: final result: FAIL
  ssh output: root@2.2.2.2: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

You have to replace `1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2` with the IP addresses or hostnames of your SSH servers. The string in `fgrep` should also be edited if you want to accept something else than just "publickey".

Answer (score -1):

If you need *nix solution, you can also hook into OpenSSH sources.
If Windows suitable for you - you can also try some .NET commercial libraries, they are much handier than OpenSSH sources :)