# Linux (bash): how to list available SSH authentication methods for local host?

Tags: linux, ssh

Is there a way to list all available SSH authentication methods for the *local* host using command line? Basically, I want to see the same list which the server would announce when trying to connect from a (remote) client.

Note: I do not want to search through `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, as this will require too much understanding of which authentication methods do in general exist (e.g. `sshd_config` may just be emtpy)

Comment: Maybe connect to the server with some debugging or verbose arguments set?

Comment: And how would I do that from Linux command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ssh -v server and look for the first "Authentications that can continue" line.

Comment: Thanks! I'd never expected such an easy solution.

Answer (score 7):

There is better way from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3613342/751932) + modified by me for localhost case:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=none -o NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost=yes localhost
```

Answer (score 5):

`nmap` can do this too using [`ssh-auth-methods`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssh-auth-methods.html):

```
nmap -p 22 --script ssh-auth-methods localhost
```

Example output:

```
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-08-16 12:07 +07
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000087s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
| ssh-auth-methods: 
|   Supported authentication methods: 
|     publickey
|_    password

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.26 seconds
```

What it does behind the scenes is in [`ssh-auth-methods.nse`](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/scripts/ssh-auth-methods.nse). Uses `libssh2` to connect with a random username and lists out the possible authentication methods.

(It's possible to print out the effective sshd configuration options with `sshd -T`, this will show what options are in effect even if `sshd_config` is empty. For this use case running `sshd -T | egrep 'permitrootlogin|authentication'` would be useful.)